# how to assign color shade values to a continuous variable by custom intervals?

Tags: r, plot, colors, color-palette

I have a vector "p" representing probabilities and a vector "age" representing the age of a subject (as the test is repeated several time per year, it is fine to have more than one p for each age).
My problem is that need to plot the results in a way that each value of p is associated to a color ranging from green to yellow to red according to the value of p at 0.1 intervals (0-0.1, 0.1-02 ... 0.9-1).
for example if p is 0 the color is green, yellow if p=0.5 and red for p= 1. 
In between there should be all colour shades from green to yellow to red.
I think I got closer with the code below, the problem is that it seems that the image function is using the highest value of p as the reference value for the "red".

```
age<-c(6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
p<-c(0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3)

colors <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellow", "red"))(10)
image(as.matrix(p[1:length(p)]), col = colors, axes = F)
par(new=T)
plot(p[1:length(p)],axes=FALSE,cex.lab=1.5,
 ylab="probability",
 xlab="age",
 ylim=c(0,1),type="l",lty=1, lwd=2)
 axis(1,at=seq(1,length(age),1),lab=round(age),cex.axis=1)
 axis(2,at=seq(0,1,0.1),lab=seq(0,1,0.1),cex.axis=1,las=1)
```

As you can see the graph displays a strong red for p=0.5 and dark orange for 0.4 (basically as they where 1 and 0.9).
if anybody can help me to fix this out that would be great!
many thanks!

Comment: Try `col = colors[p*10]`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: You are right. Did not investigate the result very carefully. This one does work though: `image(as.matrix(p), col = colors[1:max(p*10)], axes = F)`

Comment: thanks Martin, really helpful!